# Deserializing a JSON file with JavaScriptSerializer()

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, javascriptserializer

the json file's structure which I will deserialize looks like below;

```
{
    "id" : "1lad07",
    "text" : "test",
    "url" : "http:\/\/twitpic.com\/1lacuz",
    "width" : 220,
    "height" : 84,
    "size" : 8722,
    "type" : "png",
    "timestamp" : "Wed, 05 May 2010 16:11:48 +0000",
    "user" : {
        "id" : 12345,
        "screen_name" : "twitpicuser"
    }
}
```

I have created a class which has the filed names as properties for JavaScriptSerializer. The code which I will use to Deserialize the json is as follows;

```
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(twitpicResponse.GetResponseStream())) {


                var responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var results = deserializer.Deserialize<Response>(responseBody);

            }
```

My problem is how I can read the user field on json file. which is like below;

```
"user" : {
    "id" : 12345,
    "screen_name" : "twitpicuser"
}
```

it has sub properties and values. how can I name them on my Response class. my response class now look like this;

```
public class Response {

    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }

}
```

what is the best case to do it?

Comment: Thanks, your question actually had the answer I was looking for in it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. You need to create a class that holds the user values, just like the response class `User`.
2. Add a property to the Response class 'user' with the type of the new class for the user values `User`.

   ```
   public class Response {

       public string id { get; set; }
       public string text { get; set; }
       public string url { get; set; }
       public string width { get; set; }
       public string height { get; set; }
       public string size { get; set; }
       public string type { get; set; }
       public string timestamp { get; set; }
       public User user { get; set; }

   }

   public class User {

       public int id { get; set; }
       public string screen_name { get; set; }

   }
   ```

**In general you should make sure the property types of the json and your CLR classes match up.** It seems that the structure that you're trying to deserialize contains multiple number values (most likely `int`). I'm not sure if the `JavaScriptSerializer` is able to deserialize numbers into string fields automatically, but you should try to match your CLR type as close to the actual data as possible anyway.

Comment: @ntziolis thanks for the reply. so id propertery inside the Reponse class should also be int I guess?

Comment: @ntziolis: You'll need to add a parameterless public constructor, if I am not mistaken

Comment: @skarmats No the `JavaScriptSerializer` and the corresponding resolver do not require you to explicitly define constructors, its much simpler than the `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: @ntziolis: I'll never get used to these differences :d Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @skarmats Actually the `JavaScriptSerializer` is the step-sibling of the other serializers, its not used anywhere within the .NET infrastructure e.g. WCF (even when using json as format). It's merely provided as a fast and simple way to serialize/deserialize json outside of WCF and other framework scenarios.

Answer (score 22):

Assuming you don't want to create another class, you can always let the deserializer give you a dictionary of key-value-pairs, like so:

```
string s = //{ "user" : {    "id" : 12345,    "screen_name" : "twitpicuser"}};
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.DeserializeObject(s);
```

You'll get back something, where you can do:

```
var userId = int.Parse(result["user"]["id"]); // or (int)result["user"]["id"] depending on how the JSON is serialized.
// etc.
```

Look at `result` in the debugger to see, what's in there.

Comment: The array indexing into the result was a nice (and obvious in hindsight) touch.  Thanks!

Comment: I get error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: changing the var result = serializer.DeserializeObject(s); with dynamic result = serializer.DeserializeObject(s); worked for me in .net 4+

Answer (score 11):

For .Net 4+:

```
string s = "{ \"user\" : {    \"id\" : 12345,    \"screen_name\" : \"twitpicuser\"}}";

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic usr = serializer.DeserializeObject(s);
var UserId = usr["user"]["id"];
```

For .Net 2/3.5:
This code should work on JSON with 1 level

samplejson.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%
string s = "{ \"id\" : 12345,    \"screen_name\" : \"twitpicuser\"}";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, object> result = (serializer.DeserializeObject(s) as Dictionary<string, object>);
var UserId = result["id"];
 %>
 <%=UserId %>
```

And for a 2 level JSON:

sample2.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%
string s = "{ \"user\" : {    \"id\" : 12345,    \"screen_name\" : \"twitpicuser\"}}";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, object> result = (serializer.DeserializeObject(s) as Dictionary<string, object>);
Dictionary<string, object> usr = (result["user"] as Dictionary<string, object>);
var UserId = usr["id"];
 %>
 <%= UserId %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a sub-class User with an id field and screen_name field, like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string screen_name { get; set; }
}

public class Response {

    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  public class User : List<UserData>
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string screen_name { get; set; }

    }


    string json = client.DownloadString(url);
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var Data = serializer.Deserialize<List<UserData>>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Page load starts here

var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
{
    api_key = "my key",
    action = "categories",
    store_id = "my store"
});

var json2 = "{\"api_key\":\"my key\",\"action\":\"categories\",\"store_id\":\"my store\",\"user\" : {\"id\" : 12345,\"screen_name\" : \"twitpicuser\"}}";
var list = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FooBar>(json);
var list2 = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FooBar>(json2);

string a = list2.action;
var b = list2.user;
string c = b.screen_name;

//Page load ends here

public class FooBar
{
    public string api_key { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string store_id { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string screen_name { get; set; }
}
```