# How to work with a nested array of elements deserialized from a JSON string

Tags: c#, json

The following JSON string is coming to an MVC Action:

```
[{"id":13},{"id":14},{"id":15,"children":[{"id":16},{"id":17},{"id":18}]}]
```

I'm using the `DeserializeObject` method of the `JavaScriptSerializer` class to deserialize the JSON string, but I am not sure how to work with the converted array after I deserialize it.

```
var result = Request["nestable-output"];                       

JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var answer = json_serializer.DeserializeObject(result);
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Have you used Google to do a simple search on this..? there are actually numerous examples / answers on how to do this on `SO` please show a little bit more effort on your part [Deserializing a JSON String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502245/deserializing-a-json-file-with-javascriptserializer)

Comment: individuals do not get points for comments and comments are not answers.. look at this as well perhaps you need to follow some of the examples http://www.tomasvera.com/programming/using-javascriptserializer-to-parse-json-objects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `DeserializeObject()` on the `JavaScriptSerializer` class, the serializer does not have any hint as to what type of objects to deserialize into other than what it can infer from the JSON structure.  So, when it sees a JSON array, it will use `object[]` and when it sees a JSON object it will use `Dictionary<string, object>`.  Knowing this, you can get your data out by casting where needed:

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, object> item in (IEnumerable)answer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("id: " + item["id"]);
    if (item.ContainsKey("children"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("children:");
        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> child in (IEnumerable)item["children"])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   id: " + child["id"]);
        }
    }
}
```

But there's a better way.  If possible, it is usually better to define some strongly typed classes and deserialize into those instead.  For example, for your JSON we could create an `Item` class like this:

```
class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Then, we can use the `Deserialize<T>()` method instead of `DeserializeObject()`.  Now it is obvious what type the data is and we can work with it easily like any other object.

```
List<Item> answer = json_serializer.Deserialize<List<Item>>(result);

foreach (Item item in answer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("id: " + item.Id);
    if (item.Children != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("children:");
        foreach (Item child in item.Children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   id: " + child.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Does that help?