# C# Deserialize deep linked object

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have the following JSON data:

```
{
    "count": 2,

    "data" : {
        "items" : [
            {
                "id" : "1",
                "letterheadline" : "This is a test",
                "message" : "testing.. testing..",
                "dateEntered" : "2018-01-01 18:00"
            },

            {
                "id" : "2",
                "letterheadline" : "Message two",
                "message" : "testing.. testing.. testing..",
                "dateEntered" : "2018-02-01 18:00"
            },


        ]
    }

}
```

I am trying to parse it into my own object that uses different values, i.e:

```
public class Message 
{
    public string title {get; set;}

    public string body {get; set;}

    public DateTime entryDate {get; set;}
}

public class Messages
{
    public int itemCount {get; set;}

    public List<Message> messages {get; set}
}
```

I am using

`Messages messages = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Messages>(result);`

I have tried to use the following:

`[JsonProperty("letterheadline")]` (for example)

But I am still getting an error saying that it cannot be converted.

Is this because the JSON data itself is too deep to parse? Therefore would I need to create a new property `Data` inside my object that contains a list of `Messages`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing a JSON file with JavaScriptSerializer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502245/deserializing-a-json-file-with-javascriptserializer)

Comment: `[JsonProperty]` is for JSON.NET (NewtonSoft.Json), `JavaScriptSerializer` is the old, deprecated, built-in JSON library. Use the one you want, but don't mix them

Comment: @Attersson - thanks I get that and I understand the concept but will I need to create another property for "data" which contains a list of "items"? What type would data be? Also how will I map the field names to the one in my class as they are not the same??

Comment: Did you try using Newsoft.JSON ?

Comment: Try auto-generating your data model using one of the tools from [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON object string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674).  `[JsonProperty("letterheadline")]` is a [tag:json.net] attribute, it doesn't work for `JavaScriptSerializer` as explained in [JavaScriptSerializer - custom property name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32487483/3744182).